# execute a sql script file from cx_oracle?

Tags: python, database, cx-oracle

Is there a way to execute a sql script file using cx_oracle in python.

I need to execute my create table scripts in sql files.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[PEP-249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/), which cx_oracle tries to be compliant with, doesn't really have a method like that.

However, the process should be pretty straight forward.  Pull the contents of the file into a string, split it on the ";" character, and then call .execute on each member of the resulting array.  I'm assuming that the ";" character is only used to delimit the oracle SQL statements within the file.

```
f = open('tabledefinition.sql')
full_sql = f.read()
sql_commands = full_sql.split(';')

for sql_command in sql_commands:
    curs.execute(sql_command)
```

Comment: Splitting on `;` will fail if there are string literals that contain semicolons; this might take a little bit of simple scanning.

Comment: Agreed - that was my point when I said "I'm assuming that the ";" character is only used to delimit the oracle SQL statements within the file."  You stated the obvious issue more clearly though.  Thanks!

Comment: Also assumes that the _only delimiter is `;`_.  Which is _usually_ the case, but if the sql script contains things like stored procedures, then the delimiter gets changed before defining the procedure...

Comment: we use ~ character when script contains procedures/triggers etc.

Answer (score 13):

Another option is to use SQL*Plus (Oracle's command line tool) to run the script. You can call this from Python using the `subprocess` module - there's a good walkthrough here: http://moizmuhammad.wordpress.com/2012/01/31/run-oracle-commands-from-python-via-sql-plus/.

For a script like `tables.sql` (note the deliberate error):

```
CREATE TABLE foo ( x INT );

CREATE TABLER bar ( y INT );
```

You can use a function like the following:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def run_sql_script(connstr, filename):
    sqlplus = Popen(['sqlplus','-S', connstr], stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    sqlplus.stdin.write('@'+filename)
    return sqlplus.communicate()
```

`connstr` is the same connection string used for `cx_Oracle`. `filename` is the full path to the script (e.g. `'C:\temp\tables.sql'`). The function opens a SQL*Plus session (with '-S' to silence its welcome message), then queues "@filename" to send to it - this will tell SQL*Plus to run the script.

`sqlplus.communicate` sends the command to stdin, waits for the SQL*Plus session to terminate, then returns (stdout, stderr) as a tuple. Calling this function with `tables.sql` above will give the following output:

```
>>> output, error = run_sql_script(connstr, r'C:\temp\tables.sql')
>>> print output

Table created.

CREATE TABLER bar (
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command

>>> print error
```

This will take a little parsing, depending on what you want to return to the rest of your program - you could show the whole output to the user if it's interactive, or scan for the word "ERROR" if you just want to check whether it ran OK.

Comment: the accepted answer does not work in the case of PL/SQL .. this sqlplus bit does ok in that case.

Comment: if anyone gets file not found errors, ensure you use the full path of the .sql file and also add sqlplus to PATH variables.

Answer (score 1):

Into cx_Oracle library you can find a method used by tests to load scripts: [run_sql_script](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/5728cf534e24319640b52ea0e93c5042fe210f22/test/test_env.py#L154)

I modified this method in my project like this:

```
   def run_sql_script(self, connection, script_path):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    statement_parts = []
    for line in open(script_path):
        if line.strip() == "/":
            statement = "".join(statement_parts).strip()
            if not statement.upper().startswith('CREATE PACKAGE'):
                statement = statement[:-1]
            if statement:
                try:
                    cursor.execute(statement)
                except Exception as e:
                    print("Failed to execute SQL:", statement)
                    print("Error:", str(e))
            statement_parts = []
        else:
            statement_parts.append(line)
```

The commands into script file must be separated by "/".
I hope it can be of help.

Comment: Wow, thank you for unearthing this old question and providing this link. Very interesting! Although the method used in the `run_sql_script` is rather crude.