# using declare cursor with cx_oracle

Tags: python, cursor, cx-oracle

I am trying to parse an sqlscript file based on a delimiter ";" and then subsequently call Cx_Oracle to connect and execute statements on the DB server. I have run into an issue with a cursor related block of code. My call structure is thus:

```
 ScriptHandle = open(filepath)
 SqlScript = ScriptHandle.read()
 SqlCommands = SqlScript.split(';')
    for sqlcommand in SqlCommands:
        print sqlcommand,'\n'*3
        if sqlcommand:  
            ODBCCon.ExecuteWithCx_Oracle(cursor, sqlcommand)
```

The problem I have comes with the following sql block:

```
DECLARE CURSOR date_cur IS (select calendar_date 
        from cg_calendar dates
        where dates.calendar_date between '30-Jun-2014' and '31-Jul-2015'
        and global_business_or_holiday = 'B');

BEGIN
FOR date_rec in date_cur LOOP
insert into fc_pos
SELECT PP.acctid,
        PP.mgrid,
        PP.activitydt,
        PP.secid,
        PP.shrparamt,
        PP.lclmktval,
        PP.usdmktval,
        SM.asset_name_1,
        SM.asset_name_2,
        SM.cg_sym,
        SM.fc_local_crncy_cd,
        SM.fc_local_crncy_id,
        SM.fc_trade_cd,
        substr(SM.asset_name_1, 17,3) as against_crncy_cd
    FROM FC_acct_mgr AM, asset SM, ma_mktval PP
WHERE PP.dw_asset_id = SM.dw_asset_id
AND PP.secid = SM.asset_id
AND PP.activitydt = date_rec.calendar_date
AND AM.acctid = PP.acctid
AND AM.mgrid = PP.mgrid
AND SM.asset_categ_cd = 'FC';
END LOOP;
END;
```

The above python parse step disassociates the above code based on delimiter ";" where as I need to treat above as one block starting at the DECLARE and ending at the END;

How can I accomplish it from python end. I have been unable to make any headway on this and this is a legacy process flow that I am automating.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parse SQL file with PL/SQL and DML/DDL using cx\_Oracle in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10137495/parse-sql-file-with-pl-sql-and-dml-ddl-using-cx-oracle-in-python)

Comment: Hello I followed the instruction on the above mentioned hyperlink for parsing sql file with PL/SQL and DML/DDL using cx_Oracle. I switched to using SQLPLus using sub_process call from python. I hit a snag though: trying to run the above querry with all the select statement replaced by a NULL never returns where as removing the above PL/SQL block from the script file returns with everything executed as expected and quickly.

Comment: That's because the select is in the middle of a loop; you're looping infinitely.

Comment: Thanks Ben. After further research, I figured out that the issue was that I was not ending the PL/SQL blocks with a trailing / which was setting off an infinite loop where SQlPlus was waiting for further input from the script. I think I am in business now. Thanks for pointing me to subprocess way of doing things.I reckon its much cleaner and provides a clear delineation between producer and consumer of the SQL step.