# How to execute .sql file on cx_oracle?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

I want to execute a .sql file using cx_Oracle. I have to execute many files and the statements may or may not contain ';' before termination. I have gone though following solution

```
f = open('tabledefinition.sql')
full_sql = f.read()
sql_commands = full_sql.split(';')

for sql_command in sql_commands:
    curs.execute(sql_command)
```

but this does not work. 
Is there any way to pass file as parameter like i do for connection as follows:

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('server', 'port', service_name='service_name')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='password', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

like sql_file = 'mysql.sql' ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"does not work."*? Please add the relevant error messages you get. Also, splitting an sql with semicolon may work for multiple SQL queries, but will definitely fail for PL/SQL blocks. Show us some sample entries in the sql file which you want to run.

Comment: Ideally from command prompt I used command -> user/password@host:port/db_service .@my_sql.sql . so I want to know if there is a way to have that .@my_sql.sql as parameter to connect function ?

Comment: So, what about [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797593/4134674) from the question you copied that code snipped from?

Comment: I can do that using os.system or subprocess.Popen() but my question is to achieve my goal by using cx_Oracle

Comment: In that case you have obviously seen and tried the correct answer. It still applies; there is no way to pass a file to cx_oracle. Even if there was, it would still rely on the file to have the correct format (just as much as the solution you tried does). So, if you need help with bringing the file content into a format that cx_oracle can parse, then please add the information @KaushikNayak asked for.

Comment: Hi @Elric, I just want to answer your other questions that you removed when I typing the answer, for the split problem in python. feel free to remove this after you saw.

str = 'service-name:20.1.2service name 31.341 sername3412'
''.join([('\n' if ind != 0 and str[ind-1] in "0123456789" and char not in "0123456789." else '') + char for ind, char in enumerate(str)])

Comment: @MingChu: Thanks for the solution. It worked :-D

Comment: @Elric please open the question and let others reference;)

Answer (score 1):

You can run the SQL as is using the module:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
```

**Then:**

```
sqlrun = Popen(['sqlplus', 'User/Pass@DBINSTANCE'], shell=False , stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE , encoding='utf8')

sqlrun.stdin.write('@' + 'tabledefinition.sql')

stdout, stderr = sqlrun.communicate()
```

return status: `sqlrun.returncode`
Output strings: `stdout`, `stderr`

This for Unix shell execution.
NOTE: also tested successfull on powershell