# How to iterate the sql files present in the directory and pass the file names as input to execute the query present in the files?

Tags: python, oracle

I am trying to execute the query mentioned in the .sql file. The .sql file is present in the directory. I want to iterate the .sql files present in the directory and want to pass the file names for the query execution present in the .sql file.

I have tried the hard coding of the .sql files present in the directory. But, if I add more .sql to the directory,every time I need to add them in script. So, it helps if I can get any help using loops.

```
    import glob
    import os
    import cx_Oracle
    import datetime
    import time


    print("the files are...")
    os.chdir("./SQLs")
    for file in glob.glob("*.sql"):
        print(file)

    print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------")

    try:
        print("Conencting DB")
        con = cx_Oracle.connect(
            'USERNAME/PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/SERVICENAME')
    print("DB Connection Success")

    time.sleep(3)

    print("Executing all the SQLs present in the path" + os.getcwd())

    time.sleep(2)

    #Execute SQL1.sql
    str1 = open('SQL1.sql', 'r').read()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    SQLQuery = str1
    cursor.execute(SQLQuery)
    con.commit()

    #Execute SQL2.sql
    str2 = open('SQL2.sql', 'r').read()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    SQLQuery = str2
    cursor.execute(SQLQuery)
    con.commit()

    #Execute SQL3.sql

    str3 = open('SQL3.sql', 'r').read()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    SQLQuery = str3
    cursor.execute(SQLQuery)
    con.commit()

    #Execute SQL4.sql
    str4 = open('SQL4.sql', 'r').read()
    cursor = con.cursor()
    SQLQuery = str4
    cursor.execute(SQLQuery)
    con.commit()



    print("execution success: Queries Mentioned in the files are executed.")


except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    print("There is a problem with Oracle", e)
    print("Terminating connection")

    time.sleep(3)
finally:
    if cursor:
        cursor.close()
    if con:
        con.close()


print("DB Connection terminated, exiting")
time.sleep(2)
```

I expect, instead of assigning the filenames to variable every time. The for loop should fetch the file names present in the directory and the .sql file is passed as input.

Comment: Does the `print(file)` in the `glob.glob` loop work? Couldn't you re-use that structure to process the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just ned then to include all the code in your `for loop`:

```
import glob
import os
import cx_Oracle
import datetime
import time



try:
    print("Conencting DB")
    con = cx_Oracle.connect(
        'USERNAME/PASSWORD@HOST:PORT/SERVICENAME')
    print("DB Connection Success")
    cursor = con.cursor()
    os.chdir("./SQLs")
    for file in glob.glob("*.sql"):
        print("Executing all the SQLs present in the path" + os.getcwd())
        SQLQuery = open(file, 'r').read()
        cursor.execute(SQLQuery)
        con.commit()

        print("execution success: Queries Mentioned in %s are executed." % file)


except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
    print("There is a problem with Oracle", e)
    print("Terminating connection")

    time.sleep(3)
finally:
    if cursor:
        cursor.close()
    if con:
        con.close()


print("DB Connection terminated, exiting")
time.sleep(2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may read the SQL files inside the loop

```
for file in glob.glob("*.sql"):
    fh    = open(file,'r')
    query = fh.read()
    cursor.execute(query)
    fh.close()
```

This works if each of your SQL file has a single SQL statement. If not, you should consider using the techniques discussed [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12797593/7998591) to split the contents of the file further